# How to hide execl result on C and return it to variable?

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    char result;
    printf("Run script...\n");
    result = execl ("/usr/bin/wget", "wget", "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", NULL);
    printf("Stop script\n");

    return 0;
}
```

After execution I see that result is

```
Run script...
--2020-03-25 17:02:52--  https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
Resolving speed.hetzner.de (speed.hetzner.de)... 88.198.248.254, 2a01:4f8:0:59ed::2
Connecting to speed.hetzner.de (speed.hetzner.de)|88.198.248.254|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104857600 (100M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘100MB.bin.3’
```

It is not normal. So questions:

1. How I can hide output in STDOUT from `execl` function?
2. Why code after `execl` is not executed?
3. How to redirect `execl` output as string to variable for next analyze?

Comment: Note that [`execl` replaces the current process](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) -- it does not spawn a new process.  So if it's successful none of the code after the `execl` call itself will be executed.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `system` of maybe `popen` instead of `execl`

Comment: Redirect standard output to `/dev/null` (closing it is not a good idea; the `wget()` program is entitled to a working `stdout`.  If you want to capture the output, then `popen()`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Okey, I can use system... But how I can hide output using system() function?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no no no.. Redirect must be developed in C application. It is real?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear.  If you don't want to see the output, send it to `/dev/null`, which is redirection — but you do it in your program with `open()`, `dup2()` and `close()`.  If you want to capture the output, do you want that in a file (different redirection file name; otherwise the same) or capture it via a pipe (use `popen()` before `execl()`.  In all circumstances, if `execl()` succeeds, that program completely replaces the current program.  Code after `execl()` is only executed if `execl()` fails.  You may need to `fork()` first; `popen()` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you require but... if you're okay with `boost` you might want to look at [`boost.process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io).  It's got all you could want and more besides.